# VB .NET NullReferenceException, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when it seemingly is

Tags: vb.net

as the title reads, I am getting a NullReferenceException that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". This is a legacy WinForms app that I am working on so keep in mind the structure of the code is not my doing. I am trying to compare a recordset before and after a change is made to it. I am hitting my issue in trying to make a copy of  the old recordset.

Here is my code to populate the copy of the old data, which is in a module:

```
Public Function Prevdata(ByRef table As ADODB.Recordset) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pData As New ADODB.Recordset

    table.MoveFirst()

    If Not table.BOF And table.EOF Then
        While Not table.EOF
            For i = 0 To table.Fields.Count - 1
                pData.AddNew()
                pData(table.Fields(i)).Value = table.Fields(i).Value
            Next

            pData.Update()
            table.MoveNext()

        End While
    End If
    PrevData = pData
End Function
```

And here is my code in one of the forms. These are just with my other variable declarations at the top of the file. GetData just simply creates a recordset:

```
Public pData As ADODB.Recordset = GetData(tableName)
Public pDataC As ADODB.Recordset = PrevData(pData)
```

I get the error in the module in PrevData anywhere where "table" is referenced. I appreciate any help.

Comment: pData is a RecordSet without any fields.  So pData(table.Fields(i)) will always fail.

Comment: @HansPassant but I'm getting the error with "table" not being an object reference. The error first triggers at table.MoveFirst().

Comment: So you've got more than one bug, that happens.  Looks like you'll have to debug GetData(), it returned Nothing.  Field initializers like that are quite risky, the run before the constructor completed.

Comment: @HansPassant I know GetData works because isolating it, I can print records.

Comment: That's why I'm confused. I can access pData just fine, but I have trouble with pDataC.